# Continue writing in same line of file

Tags: python, file-io

I have opened the file I want to write to using:

```
data = open('input','a')
```

using a loop, I want to write some words to the file in the same line. And after every loop iteration I want to add a newline character.

```
while loop:
    for loop:
        /* do something */
        if some_condition:
            data.write(str(tag)+"")
    data.write("\n")
```

My expected output was:

```
city mountain sky sun
bay lake sun tree
```

But I'm getting:

```
city 
mountain 
sky 
sun

bay 
lake 
sun 
tree
```

How can I change my code to get the expected output? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure about your condition?  Are you on Windows?

Comment: @Ayman: I'm on ubuntu

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove the newline at the end of `tag` before writing it.

```
data.write(str(tag).rstrip('\n'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while loop:
for loop:
    /*do something
    */
    if some_condition:
        data.write(str(tag)+"")
data.write(" ")
```

In other words, remove the data.write("\n");

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `data.write("\n")` .