# Output of python script that run after raspberry pi boot

Tags: python, cron, raspberry-pi, output, autorun

I have a issue with output of my python script that autorun after raspberry pi boot and write its output in output.txt file that i have created using crontab. My code is something like this:

```
while True:
f=open('test.txt','w+')
d_date = datetime.datetime.now()
reg_format_date = d_date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
print(reg_format_date)
f.write(reg_format_date)        
for x in range (27,14,-1):
    key_in=GPIO.input(x)
    if key_in==0:
         y='1'
         print(y)
        f.write(y)              

    else:
        y='0'
        print(y)
        f.write(y)
    f.close()
```

In crontab i have write like this

```
@reboot python /home/pi/test.py >> /home/pi/output.txt&
```

output of my script is:

```
2017/08/13 01:49:12 
0
1
1
1
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

format of output that i want:                                                            2017/08/12 01:33:28  0111100000000

Answer (score 0):

From help(print):

Help on built-in function print in module builtins:

```
print(...)
    print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout)

    Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
    Optional keyword arguments:
    file: a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
    sep:  string inserted between values, default a space.
    end:  string appended after the last value, default a newline.
```

So in order to print on the same line your code will be modified such that you would place a comma after the first print so that it does not goes to the new line and would look like:

```
while True:
f=open('test.txt','w+')
d_date = datetime.datetime.now()
reg_format_date = d_date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
print(reg_format_date),
f.write(reg_format_date)        
for x in range (27,14,-1):
    key_in=GPIO.input(x)
    if key_in==0:
         y='1'
         print(y,end='')
        f.write(y)              

    else:
        y='0'
        print(y,end='')
        f.write(y)
    f.close()
```

Comment: it is ok with print function but when it write in a file it goes to new line. so how to write in a same line in a file

Comment: For this please refer to the post:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17290829/continue-writing-in-same-line-of-file

Comment: when i run the code manually by F5 its output will be 2017/08/22 11:46:08 1111111111111 but if it is auto run using crontab iwhen it write in a file it goes to newline

Comment: I have tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17290829/continue-writing-in-same-line-of-file but result is still same. i have no idea how to get expected output